# How reset PTS while converting with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, transcode, pts

While converting *.ts file with ffmpeg, I want to set the start pts to be 10, or other pts. How can I do that?

Some people said [setpts](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts) can help. I tried, but failed. Maybe my command is not correct, so what is the correct way?

Comment: Generate timestamps from a "live source" and rebase onto the current timebase:  
setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART) / (TB * 1000000)', this command is deprecated

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? What is your ffmpeg command? What did the complete ffmpeg console output show?